# Spark Kafka: understanding offset management with enable.auto.commit

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-structured-streaming, spark-kafka-integration

according to the Kafka documentation offset in Kafka can be managed using `enable.offset.commit` and `auto.commit.interval.ms`. I have difficulties understanding the concept.

For example I have a Kafka that shall batch load everyday and only shall load the new entries since the last loading process. How do I configure both parameters and what are the pros and cons of auto offset management?

This site: https://www.learningjournal.guru/courses/kafka/kafka-foundation-training/offset-management/ states the interval is normally set to 5 seconds. Does this mean the latest offset is  updated 5 seconds after Kafka ran or genereally after 5 seconds the stored offset is updated regardless of the last run? If Kafka stores the offset itself how does the retrieving process work?

There is the starting offset parameter `startingOffsets`. How can I retrieve the last auto commited offset. Currently I understand you can set it only to earliest for batch or a manually input.

Edit:
Added Code

```
spark.sparkContext.setCheckpointDir("directory")

df = spark.read.format("kafka") \
    .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", bootstrap_server) \
    .option("kafka.sasl.mechanism", "PLAIN") \
    .option("kafka.security.protocol", "SASL_SSL") \
    .option("kafka.sasl.jaas.config", jaas_config) \
    .option("kafka.group.id", parameter_group)\
    .option("startingOffsets", parameter_offset_start) \
    .option("endingOffsets", parameter_offset_end) \
    .option("subscribe", topic) \
    .load()
```

Comment: Linked blog is about native Kafka client, not how Spark manages offsets, which include checkpoint files. You cannot set auto commit setting in Structured Streaming

Comment: how does checkpoint files work?

Comment: It maintains state when the app is running, and can resume when stopped/restarted https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#recovering-from-failures-with-checkpointing Note that `startingOffsets` is **optional** and is documented saying _resuming will **always pick up from where the query left off**_

Comment: Thanks for the documentation. I have tried setting a checkpoint using s'park.sparkContext.setCheckpointDir()'. Then I'm doing df=spark.read.format().option...' But it still gets all data instead the newest. It seem not to work or what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "newest"? When you start a Kafka consumer, it can give the earliest available offset/data when you start the app, but when you run it again, it'll maintain the position, and not have duplicates. Are you setting `kafka.group.id` also? Please [edit] your post with your full code

Comment: I have added the code. Since starting offset is optional I have taken it out for testing but still I get all the entries from the topic instead of just ones after I run the code. To clarify the newest: I want to run the notebook each day as batch. I want to remember the offset it already loaded and on reach execution it shall only load the latest entries that hasn't been loaded yet to prevent duplicates. It works if I manually save the last offset in a database file and read it before loading but I would to do it automatically with kafka.

Comment: this is what I'm doing: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-kafka-integration.html#creating-a-kafka-source-for-batch-queries

Comment: Can you use `kafka-consumer-groups` command to describe your `parameter_group` value before, after, and in between a few batch runs? Are any offsets stored in Kafka? If they're not, you might want to check you're using a Spark version that supports that option. Also, you should be using `option("checkpointLocation` on whatever output stream you're writing to